# No intellisense for bower.json on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: bower, visual-studio-2017

Does VS2017 have intellisense for bower.json on ASP.Net MVC 5 projects?

This [page](https://webtooling.visualstudio.com/package-managers/bower/) shows the intellisense working, but I couldn't make it work on my VS.

Comment: You probably already checked this, but is the schema pointing at the right location? Should be http://json.schemastore.org/bower

Comment: Actually the problem seemed to be related to corporate proxy as it just worked at home.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this in VS 2017, I knew it should work because in VS 2015 works fine. Then I reported this problem to Visual Studio Developer Community and they reply day after saying:

> We have fixed the problem in an upcoming release Visual Studio 2017
>   15.5 Preview 2

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/129661/aspnet-core-bower-intellisense-not-working.html